# How to negate a ? (question character) character in golang regexp

Tags: regex, go

Following regex matches

```
"(?i).*((OR|AND) ([0-9]+=[0-9]+)).*[?]"
```

with string

```
"select or 1=1 AND id = ?"
```

but I am looking to negate '?' in regexp to not match with this string. 
I tried negating it with a cap right before '?' but its not working

```
"(?i).*((OR|AND) ([0-9]+=[0-9]+)).*[^?]"
```

Comment: Try `"(?i).*((OR|AND) ([0-9]+=[0-9]+))[^?]*$"`

Comment: Is it what you need? Or do you need `(?i)\b(OR|AND) (\d+\s*=\s*\d+)\b`. Please explain in words  what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response Wiktor, I want to match this string "select or 1=1 AND id =" but it should not match if followed by '?', like "select or 1=1 AND id =?" or "select or 1=1 AND id = 2 union all select * from table where id=?' should not match.